# Crawl multiple pages with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

**Objective**

To make a two level deep web crawler with Scrapy and Python.

**Problem**

The website is in a structure that for 1 page, there is approximately 10 items that the crawler is following the link and extracting the right data. The problem is that this structure is recursive for 10 pages, but the links for those last pages are change and are note directed to home1, but home2. For page 2 to 10, we want the crawler doing the same routine, because the pattern that the crawler is respecting, is recursively repeated for those pages.

**Website structure**

```
->website.com
-->          /home1
--->               /page/2
-->          /home2/doc/item
```

I can acess data from the first level with the next crawler.

**First level crawler**

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from mySpider.items import Item
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name="spider"
    allowed_domains = ["website.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://website.com/home1/"]

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('(/home2/doc/item((?!:).)*$'),), callback="parse_item", follow=True)]

    def parse_item(self, response):
            item = Item()
            name = response.xpath('//h3/text()')[0].extract()
            item['name'] = name
            return item
```

Comment: Welcome to the site: you may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your problem however if you are trying to crawl multiple URL's from the first page you can list them in the start_urls array. This will let you crawl each of the pages independently.

```
start_urls = [
    "https://website.com/home1/",
    "https://website.com/home2/",
    "https://website.com/home3/"
]
```

If however, you want to crawl home1 and track record the order of the URL's so that you can crawl them in the following home2, home3, etc. you can either create a global list and save the URLs to the list. Another option would be to create a list of URL's and pass them to the following requests using the meta attribute with a scrapy.Request.

Please clarify, it is difficult to understand the use case.